# how to add relation between sub class a Tag class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop, ef-code-first, code-first

Go to ParentI have five classes :

[image]

1.post :parent

2. and 3 sub class :article,news.advertisement

3.tags

How can I craate relation between 3 sub class and Tags.

each class :article ,news,advertisement has 0 or many tags .
please help me.

```
public abstract  class Post
    {


        protected string Title { get; set; }

        protected string Content { get; set; }
        protected DateTime AddDate { get; set; }
        protected bool IsReady { get; set; }
        public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Member")]
        public int MemberID { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public int Views { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Article:Post
    {
       [Key]
        public int ArticleId { get; set; }
       public IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }
 public sealed class Tag
    {
       [Key]
        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }



    }

public class News : Post
    {
       [Key]
        public int NewsId { get; set; }
       public IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Entity Framework inheritance

You're using inheritance in the code first model. By default, EF will use a [one table per hierarchy](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) strategy for the inheritance. It will put all columns in one table, along with a 'Discriminator' column, which holds the name of the type ('Article', 'News' or 'Advertisement' in your case).

The result of this is that EF will try to create one table with three key columns, in effect creating a composite key. You also try to have three `Tags` properties in one table. That won't work.

As with all inheritance, put common properties and behavior in the base class. In this case, remove the `ArticleId`, `NewsId` and `AdId`. Create one `Id` property in the `Post` class. Move the `Tags` property to the base class for now as well. See the next section on how to configure it in EF.

## Entity Framework configuration

When you create an `int` property named `Id` on a class, EF will automatically make it an auto-incrementing primary key. With inheritance, you'll only need one primary key column, because there'll be one record for each concrete type, whether it's a `News`, `Article` or `Advertisement`.

Regarding the `Tags`, you're creating a many-to-many relationship. So, each `Post` should have `ICollection<Tag> Tags` and each `Tag` should have `ICollection<Post> Posts`. Make the collections `virtual` to enable lazy loading.

## Solution sample

You can use the following EF code first classes:

```
  public abstract class Post {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } 
    // etc...
  }

  public class Article : Post {}

  public class News : Post {}

  public class Advertisement : Post {
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
  }

  public class Tag {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
  }

  public class PostsContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
  }
```